# Using JavaScript-Load-Image library to load an image from a file and it quadruples the size of the image

Tags: javascript, image, orientation, exif, loadimage

Using [JavaScript-Load-Image](https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Load-Image) function `loadImage(...)`. But the base64 string is roughly 2-4x longer than loading it via `FileReader()`.

I'm already dealing with large files so they cannot be so much larger.

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function() {
    console.log('initial length:', this.result.length);
};
reader.readAsDataURL(image_file);
```

vs.

```
loadImage(
        file,
        function (img) {
            console.log('resized length:', img.toDataURL().length);
        },
        {
            orientation: true
        }
    );
```

some results:

24839 vs. 107482

2498383 vs. 5898430

2391783 vs. 5955498

Comment: Yes, base64 encoding increases the size. What's your question?

Comment: They are both encoding in base64 and result in two very different sizes

Comment: ... and your question is why are they different sizes? See, questions typically have a question mark. As for why they are different, from that page you linked to, the library performs some kind of transformation on the images. Note that you're also calling [`toDataUrl()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL), which seems to indicate `img` is a `canvas` element, which would also add some overhead, and the default image format is "image/png", which may differ from the original format...

Comment: thanks looking into png

Comment: that was it, forcing `toDataUrl('image/jpeg')` solved my filesize issue.

Answer (score 0):

`img.toDataURL()` needed to be `img.toDataURL('image/jpeg)` to force saving as more compressed jpg instead of png